# BCrypt в PostgreSQL | Разные версии (2a и 2b) работают с одинаковым хэшем

Tags: postgresql, bcrypt

Мой бэкэнд работает с алгоритмом версией `2b`. Сейчас мне понадобилось сверять хэши прямо в базе. И тут оказалось, что `pgcrypto` работает с алгоритмом версией `2a` (я даже сначала не понял почему не пропускает).

После я попробовал взять тот же хэш, поменять в нём версию, и он прошёл проверку!

```
SELECT public.crypt('#5656243lolkek243wV#', '$2a$12$CSXLdzf7kZS7i9/qDpZbS.bS5fcf7HXCUO.j5CPCBvIEjUcOs48Py') = '$2a$12$CSXLdzf7kZS7i9/qDpZbS.bS5fcf7HXCUO.j5CPCBvIEjUcOs48Py'

 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 строка)
```

Причём учтите, что я просто поменял `b` на `a` в хэше! В связи с этим два вопроса:

1. Как всё-таки оставить `2b` на бэкэ и использовать `2a` из `pgcrypto`?
2. Почему хэш `2b` пропускается в `2a`?

Comment: [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36225192) пишут, что между 2a и 2b нет разницы

Comment: @andreymal, знаю, я всё это видел. Проблема в том, что в мете хэша (что в `$`) указаны разные версии, и из-за этого не проходит